# How can I use fragments in the same frame or layout and display them one by one?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-linearlayout, fragment

Here is a screenshot of my tablet application (not using fragments for now):

[image]

So as you can see, there is a little menu on the left with icon for each one of my activities.

Currently, these icons launches new activities, but I would like them to launch fragmentactivity in the frame on the right, so everything would be in the same pannel.

But after reading carefully posts and docs about fragments, I can only see that fragments are displayed at the same time:

from here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/details" android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, in order to display different fragments in the same place, what should I do?
I guess that playing on View=gone is the worst idea I can have, isn't it?

Thank a lot for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to migrate your activities to fragments. You will then have, for example, a `RoutePlanner` fragment, a `TrafficIssues` fragment, etc. When one of the icons is pressed, you will use the `FragmentManager` to replace the details `FrameLayout` with the corresponding fragment.

Comment: The first part is what I am currently doing, but I need to investigate the FragmentManager and how to replace the FrameLayout with the fragment, do you have a link or an example?

Comment: [This](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html) is the 'official' example, the [reference docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) also have and example, and I think they link to a few sample projects (Honeycomb Gallery, etc.).